# AWS Multi VPC VPN Sharing Possibility

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

I have 2 accounts in AWS. Both accounts have 1 custom VPC created.

Account A = VPC A
Account B = VPC B

VPC Peering is done between Account A (VPC A) to Account B (VPC B). All resources between between are accessible via Peering connection.

Problem is:
The VPN to Customer is established from Account A (VPC A). I have few resources in Account B (VPC B) that also needs to have access to Customer's VPN.

Is there any hack or solution available to achieve this ? or I will only have to go for new VPN from Account B (VPC B) ? I believe there should be some workaround for that ?

Comment: You can have a resource in VPC A and access resources of VPC B via it as you are peered it will allow.

Comment: VPC A and VPC B can talk already via Peering, but I want VPC B resources to talk to Customer's VPN via VPN connection of VPC A. Is this possible ? and I did not get you ?

Answer (score 0):

VPC peering [does not support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/invalid-peering-configurations.html#edge-to-edge-vgw) edge-to-edge transit traffic. No gateway services are accessible across a VPC peering connection, including VPC Hardware VPN connections and Direct Connect.

Your scenario requires *either* a separate VPN connection to each VPC *or* the VPN connection needs to move to a [AWS Transit Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/transit-gateway/), which allows that VPN connection to have access to VPCs that are also connected to the Transit Gateway.

Based on current pricing, a second VPN connection appears to be more cost-effective in this case, because Transit Gateway charges for the connections between VPCs and a per-gigabyte transport charge.